# SSH: Permission denied (publickey) when using jump host (bastion)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm setting up an SSH connection via a bastion host like so: `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p username@bastion" username@targetserver`

It gives me an error: *username@targetserver: Permission denied (publickey)*

But it works if I run it like so:
`ssh username@bastion` and then from the bastion `ssh username@targetserver`

The log on the *bastion* host shows my src host authenticated successfully but then the disconnection happens.

Logs from bastion:

```
Oct 26 23:25:29 BASTION_HOST sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Oct 26 23:25:36 BASTION_HOST sshd[6316]: Accepted publickey for SPONGEBOB from 1.2.3.4 port 34096 ssh2: RSA SHA256:uZuFoMk06/oPwnRSWKnm/462BbpXqE4hxEn8iQJ00rY
Oct 26 23:25:36 BASTION_HOST sshd[6316]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user SPONGEBOB by (uid=0)
Oct 26 23:25:36 BASTION_HOST systemd-logind[571]: New session 67 of user SPONGEBOB.
Oct 26 23:25:37 BASTION_HOST sshd[6388]: Received disconnect from 1.2.3.4 port 34096:11: disconnected by user
Oct 26 23:25:37 BASTION_HOST sshd[6388]: Disconnected from user SPONGEBOB 1.2.3.4 port 34096
Oct 26 23:25:37 BASTION_HOST systemd-logind[571]: Session 67 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit. Oct 26 23:25:37 BASTION_HOST sshd[6316]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user SPONGEBOB
Oct 26 23:25:37 BASTION_HOST systemd-logind[571]: Removed session 67.
```

TargetHost:

```
Oct 26 23:25:37 TARGET_HOST sshd[8931]: Connection closed by authenticating user SPONGEBOB 10.0.0.8 port 52956 [preauth]
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The key used to authenticate to the target server is the key from my src host, and not from bastion as I thought.